# How can I update user's score in Firebase using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a game. Every user creates an account. Next, after finishing a game, his score suppose to save in a firebase.

Console gives me an error: "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''"

[ViewController1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIgpK.png)

[ViewController2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9So0.png)

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to submit passedInt, integer which is nil and that's why you're getting this error.
Try to assign a value to the passedInt, just before you submit it and you will see how everything is fine.

Edit: Next time you have a problem, post the code instead of screenshots.